# adding custom button to number pad keyboard ios 6

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I am new in `IOS` & I am using `IOS 6`. I have more than one textfield in my code, one of them uses the Number pad keyboard and I want to add the custom button to it.

I am using this code:

```
 UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
    doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // locate keyboard view
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView* keyboard;
    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        // keyboard view found; add the custom button to it
        if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == TRUE)
            [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
      }
```

Selector is called, but the problem is that the `[[tempwindow.subviews]count]` is 0.

Could anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend using [InputAccessoryView](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11211721/593709)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used following code. Check it.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if(textField==txt1)
    {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                                 selector: @selector(keyboardDidShowOrHide:)
                                                     name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    }
    else
    {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    }



}
- (void) keyboardDidShowOrHide : (id) sender {
    // create custom button
    UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 427, 106, 53);
    doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [doneButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"doneup.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"donedown.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    [tempWindow addSubview:doneButton];


}
-(void)doneButton:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btntmp=sender;
    [btntmp removeFromSuperview];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    //[self setViewMovedUp:NO];
    [txt1 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by checking following links.

[Reference 1](http://www.neoos.ch/blog/37-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key)

[Reference 2](http://iphone-rahulvarma.blogspot.in/2012/03/numericpad-with-done-button.html)

**But please do not do this.**

Consider this:

- what if the layout of the number keypad changes?
- what if the colors of the keys change?
- what if the implementation of the keyboard changes such that it's no
  longer the window at index 1?
- what if the implementation of the keyboard and peripheral host change
  such that introspecting the description breaks?
- what if you're running this on iPad where the keyboard has a totally
  different layout?

Comment: The problem is that the count of the for loop is 0, i means `UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];` the `[[tempWindow.subViews] count]` is zero

Answer (score 1):

For me, I am using the following code snippet to add button to the keyboard:

```
- (void)addHideKeyboardButtonToKeyboard {
    // Locate non-UIWindow.
    UIWindow *keyboardWindow = nil;
    for (UIWindow *testWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        if (![[testWindow class] isEqual:[UIWindow class]]) {
            keyboardWindow = testWindow;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!keyboardWindow) return;

    // Locate UIKeyboard.
    UIView *foundKeyboard = nil;
    for (__strong UIView *possibleKeyboard in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {
        // iOS 4 sticks the UIKeyboard inside a UIPeripheralHostView.
        if ([[possibleKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"]) {
            for (__strong UIView *anotherPossibleKeyboard in [possibleKeyboard subviews]) {       
                if ([[anotherPossibleKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"]) {
                    foundKeyboard = possibleKeyboard;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (foundKeyboard) {
        [foundKeyboard addSubview:self.keyboardDoneButton];        
    }   
}
```

Comment: can you try to make the done button as a strong property so that it will be retained?

Comment: yes i did it as a strong property, and i still have this problem